# label Autopostback abilty

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I have Two Dropdown boxs in my Asp page. Once user changed the value one of a dropdown, it fire the Autopostback and display a new selected value on a label.

```
label.text = Convert.ToString(Convert.Int32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString())+Convert.Int32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

I just want to retrieve this label value (which reproduce dynamically ) to another text box.

Unfortunatly there is no event called AutoPostBack for labels. How can I overcome this?
please help me.

Comment: Why are you converting a string to an integer and then back to a string?

Comment: That's some downright awful code...

Comment: If the value of the label only changes when the postback of the dropdownlists are changed why cant you set the value of the textbox at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the textbox value at the time you are upadting the label value.

```
label.text = Convert.ToString(Convert.Int32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString())+Convert.Int32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString()));
textBox.text = label.text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Label_Value =Convert.ToString(Convert.Int32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString())+Convert.Int32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString()));

Textbox1.Text=Label_Value .Tostring();
```